# Accessing shared location is slow from JNLP app but works fine when app is launched from IDE

Tags: jnlp

I tried to access remotely hosted shared location through my JNLP app. Interestingly it takes much more time to load that directory content than the app is launched from IDE. Any idea?

Comment: Every JNLP application initially loads the whole application from the (remote) server which takes time. In your IDE the code is already there. Or did you use the IDE internal webbrowser? With the amount of information you supplied everything is possible - it also could be the air pressure in the server room ;-) so please add some more  information /details of your setup!

Comment: Every webstart application runs in a sandbox. That means it goes through a lot of security check which makes the process slow. In case of IDE, apps are configured to run in a non-sandbox environment, which makes it faster.

Comment: If that was the reason of beeing so slow then add it as an answer and accept it so that other people can benefit from it...